# Image loaded form redirected URL has wrong size

Tags: ios, image, swift, retina-display, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImage to load and image from the web and set it to a marker on a map. The URL of the image may change over time. Because of that I use an url redirection which stays stable and points to the original url. Unfortunatly there is something wrong with the image when loaded via the redirection. The image is always drawn double the size than it should be when loaded from the redirection url. It is drawn correctly when loaded from the original url.

I added a logging output that puts out the image size. The output for the image loaded from the redirection url is 88x88 and for the image from the original url it is 44x44. The image has a size of 88x88 pixel. I am using a simulator with retina display, therefore I think the correct size should be 44x44 points. The redirection url definitly redirects to the correct image, I checked that in the browser. How can the size be different for the same image?

My code:

```
let url=NSURL(string:"http://redirectionurl/asdf")
//  let url=NSURL(string:"http://originalurl.com/image@2x.png")


var managerCompletedBlock:(UIImage!, NSError!,SDImageCacheType,Bool) -> Void = {
            image,error,cacheType,finished in
            if(finished){
                println("finished")
                if let e = error
                {
                    if let s = e.localizedDescription
                    {
                        println(s)
                    }
                }
                log.debug("size: \(image.size.width) \(image.size.height)")
                imageToLoad.icon = image
            } else {
                println("fail!!!!");
            }
        }

self.imageManager.downloadWithURL(url, options: SDWebImageOptions.HighPriority, progress: nil, completed: managerCompletedBlock)
```

I made a screenshot. The marker on the left side is loaded from the original url and the marker on the right side is loaded from the redirection url: http://bayimg.com/JAOPmaAFp

Comment: Please download both images (original and redirected) to your PC and check whether they were sent with same headers and same file content.

Comment: @Alexander: Both are the same, except for the file name. The image from the redirection url does not have "@2x" in the filename. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there something that I should change in my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDWebImage has the following code in [SDWebImageCompat.m](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/SDWebImageCompat.m), in the SDScaledImageForKey method:

```
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        CGFloat scale = 1.0;
        if (key.length >= 8) {
            // Search @2x. at the end of the string, before a 3 to 4 extension length (only if key len is 8 or more @2x. + 4 len ext)
            NSRange range = [key rangeOfString:@"@2x." options:0 range:NSMakeRange(key.length - 8, 5)];
            if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
                scale = 2.0;
            }
        }

        UIImage *scaledImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:scale orientation:image.imageOrientation];
        image = scaledImage;
    }
```

You'll note that it's detected the standard "@2x" in the filename and is scaling the image appropriately. Looks like the key that it's checking for the @2x is, by default, just set up by the URL that's passed in, before any redirection happens.

If what you have works now, I'd probably just change your redirect URL so it ends with "@2x.png". Alternatively, from a quick glance, it looks like you can "hijack" the URL cache key by providing your own cacheKeyFilter (check the README for more info.) It's probably not intended for the purpose, but I'm guessing if you supplied a cache key filter that munged the key to always add "@2x.png" onto the end, that'd probably ensure consistent scaling behaviour.